# flex imap library

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, network-programming, imap

I'm looking for an imap library to use in flex but can't find any.

I know that can be done from scratch, but thought i should ask before reinventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is POP3/IMAP4/SMTP library ([Airxmail](http://code.google.com/p/airxmail/)) written in AS3 for AIR 1.5 and AIR 2.0.